# My search functionality isn't working in angular and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm having issues with this code, I'm trying to implement search functionality on my angular web page, but when I test this code in postman it just returns "NO USER FOUND WITH USERNAME: undefined". Also on the webpage when I provide the search query it says error 404, not found. Any help? here is the code:

```
let conn = new mysqli({
    Host: 'localhost', 
    post: 3306, 
    user: 'root', 
    passwd: '', 
    db: 'registracija'
}); 


let db = conn.emit(false, '');
```

```
app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
    const query = req.body.q;

    //const sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%${query}%'`;

    /*db.query(sql, (error, results)=>{
        if (error){
            res.status(500).send({error:'Error executing SQL query'});
        }
        else {
            res.send(results);
        }
    });*/

    db.table('users').filter({username: query}).withFields(['username','password']).get()
    .then(user =>{
        if (user){
            res.json({user});
        }
        else{
            res.json({message:`NO USER FOUND WITH username: ${query}`});
        }
    }).catch(err => res.json(err)); 
});
```

Here is the angular part of the code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  query = '';
  results: any = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  search(){
    this.http.get('/search', { params: { q: this.query}}).subscribe(results => {
      this.results = results;
    });
  }

}
```

and the html:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="query" placeholder="Enter search query" />
<button (click)="search()">Search</button>

<!-- create a container to display the search results -->
<div *ngIf="results.length">
  <h3>Search Results</h3>
  <ul>
    <!-- use the ngFor directive to iterate over the search results -->
    <li *ngFor="let result of results">
      {{ result.username }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope somebody can help me solve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You use a query parameter `q` to send the search text to the server.

But in the server you try to access this parameter with `req.body.q`. You should use `req.query.q` to access query parameters.